# In which format should I sent the values in database in PHP?

Tags: php, database-design, mysql

I am developing an application which is based on the quiz contest for competetive exams. The user can give different categories of tests, which will contain different types of questions of following types:

1. Single select,
2. Multiple select,
3. Match making,
4. Comprehension (the quetion will be a paragraph and on the basis of that there will be questions),
5. Free text (the user will have to type the answer),
6. Range (the user have to select a number from 1 to 10).

My concern is that while creating questions from admin site, how can I manage the database for above type of questions?

I have one answer column in the question table but there are six type of questions so what should be the convenient way for saving answers in the databse so that when user will give answer, I can easily check if the answer matches?

I am thinking of saving the answer in the form of XML tags. Will this be a good approach?

Answer (score 2):

Every type of question will have to be managed differently in your application and will use a different selection of data, it would be best to create multiple tables for each part of the question with that are all related to a central question table, rather than try to have one massive table.

you will want at a minimum a question table, a MC option table, a table for reading selections, a table to store rules on how to grade free text answers; or a table with enough columns for all that.

Comment: if iwill use mulitple tables then won't it be more difficult for me to match the answer?

Comment: no, basic SQL will allow you to join the tables together and questionid would be a good FK to join on. the alternative is to have a massive table where many columns will be null for each entry, which gets problematic.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have an `answers` table. This table should have a `question_id` so you know what question is being answered, and it should also help you figure out what kind of data is in the answer, assuming that the `questions` table has some sort of `question_type_id` that refers to one of the question types above.

Then, the simplest (IMO) solution: For most of these answer types, you could have a single text field to store the answer, probably no longer than the max length you'd allow for Free Text answers (assuming no more than a hundred characters or so). For the longer answers for the Comprehension type, you may want a separate table, call it `large_answers`, for holding very large text objects and store the answer there, and in your main `answers` table refer to the `large_answers` by an optional `large_answer_id` field.

I'm not sure why XML would be needed for this.

So:

```
Questions
  question_id (unique key)
  question_type_id
  (other fields that don't have an impact on this solution)
```

Answers
  Answer_id (unique key)
  question_id (refers to questions.question_id)
  answer_text (non-null, but for large_answers, maybe just store the first n characters, as a preview)
  large_answer_id (optional, refers to large_answers.large_answer_id)

large answers
  large_answer_id (unique key)
  large_answer_text (CLOB type)

Or you could do it like this:

```
Questions
  (as before)
```

Answers
  Answer_id (unique key)
  question_id (refers to questions.question_id)
  answer_text (nullable)

large answers
  large_answer_id (unique key)
  answer_id (refers to answers.answer_id)
  large_answer_text (CLOB type, non-null)

In the above schema, you'd have the `large_answers` referring back to the answer they are associated with, instead of the `answers` having a nullable reference to a `large_answer`. Hmmm the more I think about it the more I like the second schema as I don't like the idea of a nullable `large_answer_id`, but I'm sure there's good arguments to be made for both sides... ;)

Comment: That's a great solution i have start working to implement it thank you very much

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about extraordinarily large answers.  The "large_answer" table is a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: @kevincline: The "Comprehension" type says the answer could be a paragraph, and if it's a short paragraph, the `large_answer` isn't really needed. It depends on how long the paragraph(s) are. Essay-length answers and it might be better to split it.